# Given a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$, with $\det(A) = \frac{1}{8}$, find $\det(3A)$, $\det((6A)^{-1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How do I go about solving this? The $\det(3A)$ is not simply $3\cdot\frac{1}{8}$ correct?

Comment: No, it is not.  Do you know how row operations affect the determinant?

Comment: If $A$ is $n \times n$, $\det(c A) = c^n \det(A)$.

Answer (score 3):

As matrix $A$ is $3\times3$, we have $\det{(kA)}=k^3\times\det{(A)}$ for $k \in \mathbb{C}$
$$\therefore\det{(3A)}=3^3\times\det{(A)}=3^3\times\frac{1}{8}=\frac{27}{8}$$
$$\det{(6A)^{-1}}=\bigl(\det{(6A)}\bigr)^{\!-1}=\bigl(6^3\times\det{(A)}\bigr)^{\!-1}=\Bigl(6^3\times\frac{1}{8}\Bigr)^{\mkern-5mu-1}=\frac{1}{27}$$